# WPF media formats

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mediaelement

Does WPF have built-in support for any audio and video formats? I'm going to be using the MediaPlayer and MediaElement classes to build a little media player, and for now, I don't want to have to deal with codecs and formats that .NET doesn't have native support for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WPF supports the video formats WMV, MPEG and some AVI files by default, but since it has Windows Media Player running beneath, WPF can use all the codecs installed for it

Comment: @AgentFire elaborate ?